# on ajax success running table.setData but data is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I am trying to run a report with two tabulator tables. One main table, then on click of a row it will populate a modal. All the html part works and the jquery (JS) works. I have a success function on my ajax call to set the data in the modal. But it does not seem to be waiting for the ajax to return the data. See code below. I can see the data in the console.log so the console.log seems to be running its just not pushing to the table. If I run a function to set the data manually from the console it works. So not really sure whats going on.

```
var CatVolumetable = new Tabulator("#myreport", {
//height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  placeholder:"Select Year-Month to populate Data",
  layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns:[ //Define Table Columns
    {title:"Category Name", field:"Category_name", align:"left"},
    {title:"State", field:"State",align:"center"},
    {title:"Max Quantity",field:"maxQuantity", align:"left"},
  ],
  rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    var state = row.getData().State;
    //getStoresByState(state);
    $('#drilldown').modal('toggle');

    let myUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/view_state_category_volume_drilldown/'+state;
    $.ajax({
      //$.ajax({
      url:    myUrl,
      method:   'get',
      dataType:   'json',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        ddtable.setData(data);
      }
    });

var ddtable = new Tabulator("#drilldownTable", {
  //height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  //ajaxURL:""
  placeholder:"No Data Available",
  layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns:[ //Define Table Columns
    {title:"Manager_email", field:"Manager_email"},
    {title:"Manager_name", field:"Manager_name", align:"left"},
    {title:"Store_num", field:"Store_num"},
    {title:"Street_address", field:"Street_address", align:"center"},
    {title:"City Name", field:"City_name", align:"center"},
  ],
});
```

SOLUTION:
I figured out the problem is that the data must be loaded *after* the modal is toggled (i.e. after it is visible). If I load data on the show event listener it works perfectly. Below is code with bootstrap.

```
$("#drilldown").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){
///Ajax call with success handler to load data
})
```

Comment: What I think you need to do is to load the other tabulator when you recieve data at the main tabulator. If the first tabulator is a parent element of your second tabulator this issue is because the tabulators are loaded anyway and they will update their contents once they get a response.

Comment: A parent element in the DOM? They are separate divs in the DOM. Also I should mention, if I program a delay in (500ms) it works.

Comment: Ok my bad. Do you have link to gh or anything for reproducing?

Comment: Let me see if I can I can reproduce with public api

Comment: Well crud. When I do it with a public url (pokeapi.co) it works. Seems like the delay getting the public api is long enough but when running locally on my PC it's too fast. But it should be promise based so I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is too fast for your second tabulator table

Check this [post](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/839#issuecomment-360623715)
.Use below code to set Data after drilldownTable is initialized

```
if ($("#drilldownTable").hasClass("tabulator")){
   //element has class of .tabulator
}
```

Comment: The table is initilized when the page loads. I figured out then problem though. Will post separately.